# Does a child process always run inside the parent process? Does a ... Thread...?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if I have a program that creates another process, does that created process run inside the creator?  If so, does it always have to (is there a way to attach it to another process)?

The reason that I ask is actually because I'm trying to determine whether to make a particular thread, a background thread.  Here is the scenario:

A process A is launching a program B that makes calls to wcf services.  However, I'm spawning a thread from program B to make the actual service calls.  If I set the thread to a background thread and process A crashes or terminates, will the thread terminate?  If so, how can I decouple the thread from the process?

Comment: From the description, it sounds like you're using program, process, and thread interchangeably, but they're not. Please specify exactly which you're using.

Comment: "Decoupling" a thread from a process is not possible. A thread "taken out of" a process is a process with a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Processes are independent of each other.  Parent and child process lifetimes are not explicitly coupled at all.

A thread is owned for its lifetime by the process that created it, and terminates when (if not before) the creating process exits.

If a process wishes to control another process's lifetime, it needs to have a `HANDLE` to the controlled process.  This can be gotten either by being the creator of the controlled process (here, the handle is returned from the creation call), or (given correct permissions) via [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28VS.85%29.aspx).  In .Net, this is done using `Get*` methods on [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

A process does not run within another process in windows (threads run within processes).

In your scenario, once program B terminates, the thread should also terminate.

What happens on process A will not affect the thread at all.